# Spring and Thymeleaf get 'template mode "HTML" has not been configured.' when jar moved to Linux

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have developed a website using Intellij on Windows 7, where it works OK.  Thymeleaf is the templating system.  Then I use Build artifact to create a jar file and move the jar to a Linux server.  When I try accessing a web page I get the message 'Template mode "HTML" has not been configured'.

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
```

is set in application.properties

In the pom

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.1.4-2</kotlin.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.3.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Something is implicit in the Intellij side but missing on the Linux side, but I dont see what.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML`.

Spring boot will use the default mode `HTML5`

Comment: HTML5 expects XHTML format not HTML.  The frontend people want to use HTML, which is compatible with their tools.